# Meaning of gatttool security levels (low | medium | high)

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, command-line-interface, gatt, gatttool

How does the linux [gatttool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gatttool.1.html) three security levels (low, medium, and high) correspond to BLE Security Modes and Levels? The gatttool provide 3 security levels (low, medium, and high) while BLE security spec has 4 different security levels (1, 2, 3, and 4) and at least 3 different security modes (1, 2, and mixed). I am trying to understand what does each of the security levels in gatttool (low, medium, and high) correspond to in the BLE security spec, or at least just understand what's the difference between the three.

Thanks in advance!